# Why are the results from iTtunes Search API ordered differently than a search result on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, analytics, itunes-store

I noticed that the apps returned from the [iTunes search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) for a specific search term are different (mostly in a different order) than when I search for this search term directly in the App Store app on the iOS device.

Can I get the exact same results? (How do ASO tools like Sensortower achieve this?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It's a question about an API - an Application **Programming** Interface...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question - the iTunes search API returns the results in the order they appear on the iTunes application on Windows or OS X. There is no API parameter or option to return the same results/ordering as on an iOS device.

Comment: so,in the end did you find a way to get the results that on iOS devise? Somehow I need to do this these days. i've been google it, but there's few discuss about this. I'll be very appreciate for your help.