# Is there a way to get the search result i get in the App Store app on the iOS device? ( How to get the ipa file of "App Store"? )

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, ipa, itunes-store

Updated on 2015-11-1:

One solution I am trying is to start `App Store` using `Applium`, so that I can record/monitor iOS UI elements. just like what we did `Selenium`.

Let's treat `App Store` as a standard iOS app, is it possible to:

1. uninstall `App Store` from my iphone.
2. get the `ipa file` of `App Store`
3. unzip the `ipa file` and get the `app bundle`
4. run `Appium` with `App Store's app file`

Is it possible to get `App Store` 's ipa file?

======

I want to know the position of my apps when I search on the App Store. When I use the [iTunes Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). I notice the result returned from the iTunes search API for a specific search term are different from the result on the iOS App Store app.

I found [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947339/why-are-the-results-from-ittunes-search-api-ordered-differently-than-a-search-re#) is also about this, the owner of that has find out the reason about this condition.

But there is no answer to solve this problem.

Actually I've been trying to build the search request, but it cames that the iOS Appstore is using the HTTPs request, so I don't know what to do with this.

Hope someone can help, I'll be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

There is at this time no way to specify that you want the results you would get from an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution that comes to mind is to build a search request that appears as I it came from ios in your app code.

I'm sure its possible to determine that by basically proxying an actual iPhone using say your router on your home network to log the traffic from an iphone.

Once you have that you can then basically reverse engineer the call in your app code.

Comment: If this amounts to using a "private API", Apple would reject an app using it. It's not quite clear from the question where he wants to do this searching from. But if it's from software he intends to publish on the App Store, he's got to be careful about the actual methods he uses.

Comment: no it would result the OP using the official Apple API as used by the software installed on every IOS device that already queries the store. but from the client point of view he would essentially just build a web request manually instead of using the apple provided API as that (from what the OP is saying) appears to be generating different requests to that of an iPhone

Comment: In general, if you have to reverse engineer something in an Apple API because it's not documented, they consider this "using a private API" and they don't like it.

Comment: Actually I've been trying to build the search request, but it cames that the iOS Appstore is using the HTTPs request, so I don't know  what to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can refer from Apple's guidance: [Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching), there are **too many ways of parameter combination**.(Parameters includes:*term*, *country*, *media*, *entity*, *attribute*, *callback*, *limit*, *lang*, *version*, *explicit*, *etc*.) So it's almost impossible to find out the way of combination that App Store is adapting so as to get the same search results as users get directly from App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see if you can get this to work:

### In Mac OS X:

- Launch iTunes
- Under Library menu, click on [Apps] menu.
- The iTunes will display all installed app
- Right-click on one of those apps
- Then click “Show in Finder” option

An alternative to this is simply open the directory of .ipa files stored by using this path: `User/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications`

This probably only works with apps *you* downloaded, but it is worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to listen in on https connections by installing a trusted ssl certificate on the device and running traffic through a proxy - basically performing a man-in-the-middle attack on yourself. I've previously used [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to do this - [here's the guide how to set this up](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/). That way you should be able to see exactly what request the App Store app is sending and what response it is getting. And thus it should also be possible to spoof this request and parse the results elsewhere.